# PHP Session/Array Details

Tags: php, html, cart

I got this code here that add's a product code and size to a session array, and i get the codes so i can take 1 from stock from that size:

```
if($_GET['acao'] == 'add'){
        $cod =$_GET['cod'];
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$cod])){

           $_SESSION['cart'][$cod]=$tamanhos;

            $sql="SELECT stock FROM detalhes_produtos WHERE cod_produto='$cod' AND tamanho='$tamanhos' ";
            $resultado=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sql);
            odbc_fetch_row($resultado);
            $stock  = odbc_result($resultado,1);

          $conta = $stock - 1;
        }
     }
```

And i got this code to unset the session and i wanted to get the 'tamanhos' like it is on add so i can make a query to add 1 to stock , this is the code:

```
if($_GET['acao'] == 'del'){
        $cod =$_GET['cod'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$cod])){

            $_SESSION['cart'][$cod];

           $ligaBD=odbc_connect('basededadospap','','');
           $sql="SELECT stock FROM detalhes_produtos WHERE cod_produto='$cod' AND tamanho='$tamanhos' ";
           $resultado=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sql);
           odbc_fetch_row($resultado);
            $stock2  = odbc_result($resultado,1);

           $conta1 = $stock2 + 1;
           $sql2="UPDATE detalhes_produtos SET stock='$conta1' WHERE cod_produto='$cod' AND tamanho='$tamanhos';";
           odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sql2);
           unset($_SESSION['cart'][$cod]);


        }
     }
```

But it doesnt adds one to the table , what can i do?

Comment: do you have `session_start();` on each of your page?

Comment: And your code looks pretty unsafe. SQL-Injections could be easily executed by changing the get-parameter `cod`

Comment: @Yannici I know , but it isnt really important on this project

Comment: I've tried a foreach method but it erases me everything , but , it gives me +1 in the table so thats a start

Comment: Why is your question tagged `html`?

Comment: Because its html/php

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work with this code:

```
$tmn =$_SESSION['cart'][$cod];
```

Comment: Why the thumbs down?